# Why is setState using a previous object after a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, es6-promise, setstate

I'm doing some formatting to an object by fetching strings whenever there is a URL in my object key.  When I go to set state at the end of the fetching, the displayed component is using the pre-formatted object.

The object shows up correctly in console.log of the props given to the component, as well as if console logged at the end of the function.

Why is SetState using the original object instead of the result of the promise?

```
_clicked(index) {

let clickedHouse = this.state.houses.find(obj => obj.url === index);
delete clickedHouse[`url`];
this._getNames(clickedHouse).then(res => 
  // console.log(`completedFetching`,res)
  this.setState({displayedHouse: res})
  )  
 }

_getNames(houseObj) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let namedHouse = houseObj;
  Object.keys(namedHouse).forEach(key => {
    if (namedHouse[key].includes(`https`)) {
      console.log(`fetching something`)
      this._loadJson(namedHouse[key])
      .then(result => (namedHouse[key] = result.name));
    }
   });
   resolve(namedHouse)
   })
 }
```

The goal is to display: https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/houses/10
with names instead of URLS.

Answer (score 0):

ES6 arrow functions do not have their own `this` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Inside an arrow function `this` represents the same object as outside. So `this.setState` is called on the same object as `this._getNames`.

Comment: Thanks Alex, is there a simple solution to this?  how are my bindings incorrect? how do I call setState without this?